# Drupal 6: Want to remove access restrictions on a View

Tags: drupal

I have a View with a Page display that only allows the returned data to be linked if the user is authenticated/logged in.

I simply want to remove that restriction. There is another view that looks the same except it's for Public and shows all the same data but not linked. (the data are pdf files).

On the authenticated display, next to Access in the Basic Settings it has: authenticated user. If I click that user role (not the gear for options), then I'm allowed a list of: 
Domain
None
Permission
Role

…for access restrictions. I click "None", save. But, the links are not there as an anon visitor. Same if I try by changing the user to Anonymous User. Note: In the permissions, anon has the right to see webfm attachments.

I noticed the url is like: documents-public or documents-auth so I made it just documents. No luck.

I visited the actual custom-page-type which puts the View in a content pane. I re-ordered the variants, removed all Selection Rules and that didn't do anything either.

Flushed all caches.

Somewhere, the view is still only showing a view based on whether a user is authenticated or not even though I've removed the access (it says "unrestricted" next to access) on both displays and removed all selection rules on the actual page.

I'm stuck where else to look.

Answer (score 1):

The setting you're changing (Access restrictions) is for the entire page - the page URL will return a 403 error if the criteria are met.

As to where the logic is to display/not display the link, four things come to mind:

1. If the "view mode" is set to node or teaser, it could be in the node template file.
2. The logic might be in a specific view template (click on the theme information link and see if any of the templates have been overridden).
3. The developer might have user Views Custom Fields to put the logic directly in the fields.
4. The linked content is actually restricted.

I'm sure there are other possibilities too. The main point here though is that if access was restricted for anon users, they would see a 403 error, not just some missing fields.

Comment: The views for both anon and authenticated return the same stuff, it's just that for the authenticated, the pdf files are actually linked for download instead of just shown. I think I found it. After 'none' above, I had to re-choose "with links" in a field name even though it was already set like that. Buggy. After choosing the same option, saved and it seems to be working now. Thanks.